# How to reorder telegram posts already sent (python)

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

Is it possible to change the order of sent posts on telegram channel. If so how to do that?
Let's say I have these posts sent in my telegram channel:

[image]

I wanna change the order of 2nd and 3rd posts like this:

[image]

And achieve this:

[image]

Is that possible? Or am I the funniest person in the history of programming?

Comment: Send them in the right order in the first place. If necessary wait for one message to appear before you send the next.

Comment: All posts are technically displayed on the basis of the time they are sent at. Changing the order they are sent (displayed) in, would require changing the time they are sent at. AFAIK this cannot be done once something has been executed or "sent". What is your case though anyway?

Comment: @KlausD, I sent 10 posts on my channel. And letter I had to add another post (say) somewhere between post number 4 and 5. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is **you can't** but...

You would have to display the posts in a different chat with a different order, but if you want to modify that order in the future, you would also have to delete those messages and start over again: It's too much work (and even error-prone) even if it's automated

A web frontend is a better solution to this problem